# Packets switched through Linux bridge have very high packet delay variation and latency?

Tags: bridge

I configured a very simple bridge under Debian Wheezy(kernel 3.2.0-4-686-pae). I simply created bridge interface with `brctl addbr br0` and added interfaces `eth1` and `eth2` into this bridge with `brctl addif br0 eth1` and `brctl addif br0 eth2` commands. STP is disabled. However, the latency of frames switched is very high and fluctuating. For example RTT shown in `ping` output fluctuates from 30 to 1100ms if I ping a router in the very same broadcast domain. Usually it is below 1ms. However, there seems to be no packet loss. CPU load on this Linux bridge is very low. According to `ip -s link show dev eth1` and `ip -s link show dev eth2` there are no errors or drops. Both `eth0` and `eth1` are Realtek PCI NIC's using the *8139too* LKM. What might cause such behavior? Some sort of faulty queuing?

EDIT: one of the Realtek interfaces was problematic. I formed a bridge with new NIC.

Comment: Does "one of the Realtek interfaces was problematic. I formed a bridge with new NIC" mean the problem is gone?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes. Later this NIC was not even detected by system, i.e. if I loaded the _8139too_ driver, then the _8139too 0000:00:0d.0: Chip not responding, ignoring board_ message was logged into kernel ring buffer. Finally I just replaced the NIC and now the bridge works as it should.